# Tkinter SaveAs Multiple files in Single Prompt

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to bulk convert selected images to selected format and save them in user selected directory with their existing name and new format.

```
files_list[]

def browse():
    filez = askopenfilenames(parent=window,title='Choose your images',filetypes=[("image files", ('.png', '.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.tif','.webp' ))])
    global files_list
    files_list = list(filez)

def convert():
    cformat = combo.get()
    userpath = askdirectory(title='Select Folder to Save Converted Images')
    for file in files_list:
        im = Image.open(file).convert('RGB')
        working_name = str(os.path.basename(file))
        file_extension = str(os.path.splitext(working_name)[1])
        file_extension = file_extension.replace(".", "")
        userpath = userpath + "\\"
        saving_path = userpath + "Converted_" + working_name
        saving_path = saving_path.replace(file_extension, cformat)
        im.save(saving_path, quality=95)
```

I'm doing this by adding "\" to the end of returned string from `askdirectory()` and adding file names to it.
I have also tried `SaveAs()` but i don't want to prompt user for every single file.

Is there any solution to skip adding the last slash ?
Because i am losing multi platform compatibility due to file system types(Windows uses "\" and Linux-like systems use "/")

Any advice would be great!